# Easy way to check for continents using NSLocale, NSLocaleCountryCode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocale

Is there a way to check if the user's current country is in Europe, Asia or Africa?

I working on an app that does something different for the UK and the US. I want to extend that logic so if the user's locale is set to a country in Europe, then I default to what I do for the UK. If it's outside Europe, UK, then I default to what I do for the US.

This is what I do at the moment.

```
NSString *countryCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
if ([countryCode isEqualToString:@"UK"]) {
    NSString *startString = @"£ ";
}
if ([countryCode isEqualToString:@"US"]) {
    NSString *startString = @"$ ";
}
```

Is there a simple way to check for continents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the name of the continent this way...

```
 NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
 NSString *tzName = [timeZone name];
```

Now you can handle what you need with the name (switch statements). For example in Chicago it shows: `America/Chicago`

**Another** **Option**

Use [**iOSCowboy**](https://github.com/iOSCowboy/Transcontinental) where you can use the country code (ISO 3166 Format) to return the continent.

**One more option**

You can create an array that has the countries and their continent...

Comment: This solution is not ideal in many cases. You can't differentiate between North and South america, for example. But it may be enough to check for European timezones.

Comment: @rmaddy Good point. For my purpose, timezones are good enough. For UK, Europe is +1 to +4 GMT. And for remainder of the world, I can the US.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the time zone to determine a rough approximation of the current continent.

For the complete list of time zones, you can run `sudo systemsetup -listtimezones` from macOS.

```swift
public extension TimeZone {
    var globeEmoji: String {
        let region = self.identifier.split(separator: "/").first ?? ""
        switch region {
        case "Atlantic",
             "Africa",
             "Europe",
             "GMT":
            return ""
        case "Arctic",
             "Asia",
             "Australia",
             "Indian":
            return ""
        case "America",
             "Antarctica",
             "Pacific":
            return ""
        case "Brazil",
             "CET",
             "CST6CDT",
             "Canada",
             "Chile",
             "Cuba",
             "EET",
             "EST",
             "EST5EDT",
             "Egypt",
             "Eire",
             "Etc",
             "Factory",
             "GB",
             "GB-Eire",
             "GMT+0",
             "GMT-0",
             "GMT0",
             "Greenwich",
             "HST",
             "Hongkong",
             "Iceland",
             "Iran",
             "Israel",
             "Jamaica",
             "Japan",
             "Kwajalein",
             "Libya",
             "MET",
             "MST",
             "MST7MDT",
             "Mexico",
             "Midseast",
             "NZ",
             "NZ-CHAT",
             "Navajo",
             "PRC",
             "PST8PDT",
             "Poland",
             "Portugal",
             "ROC",
             "ROK",
             "Singapore",
             "Turkey",
             "UCT",
             "US",
             "UTC",
             "Universal",
             "U-SU",
             "WET",
             "Zulu":
            print("An unusual time zone was detected. These are not usually used.")
            return ""
        default:
            print("Failed to handle time zone: \(self.identifier)")
            return ""
        }
    }
}
```